# How to preserve the original stack trace when exception is wrapped in another custom exception and rethrown

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I have created Spring boot application with the following layers

1. Controller
2. BusinessLayer
3. DAOImplLayer

Controller calls the Business layer and Business layer calls the DAOImplLayer. I have created two different custom exceptions (BusinessException and  DAOException)

In DAOImpl class I'm catching DataAccessException and throwing DAOException (with dataAccessException object in parameter since SonarQube is complaining to Either log or rethrow DataAccessException exception.)

```
catch (DataAccessException dataAccessException)
{
      throw new DAOException(dataAccessException, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, CODE_INTERNAL_SERVER,
          dataAccessException.getCause().getMessage());
}
```

In BusinessImpl I'm catching DAOException and throwing BusinessException

```
catch (SecurityDAOException e)
{
    some logic
    throw new BusinessException(e, e.type, e.code, UNABLE_TO_PROCESS_REQUEST);  
}
```

I've written common Handler class to log the exceptions.

```
  @ExceptionHandler(BusinessException.class)
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleEntityNotFound(BusinessException businessException)
  {
    if (null != businessException.getCause())
    {
      LOG.error("BusinessException: ", businessException);
    }
 some logic
  }
```

1. How to preserve the original stack trace. I am looking of something similar

   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
       at com.exception.copy.Layer3.getLayer3(Layer3.java:8)
       at com.exception.copy.Layer2.getLayer2(Layer2.java:9)
       at com.exception.copy.Layer1.main(Layer1.java:9)
2. Is it fine to have a custom exception for each layer?

Comment: Should throw just an exception and getting it in exception handler. Looks like no useful double exceptions wrapped

Comment: @JonathanJohx: I can't figure out what your comment is trying to say. Care to rewrite it in regular English?

Comment: OK, he should leave the exception is thrown instead of wrap it in a new exception. His block try and catch is not useful because he is throwing it again. Then he should   rewrite the exception handler of BusinessException.class to SecurityDAOException.class @ruakh

Answer (score 0):

Nearly every `Exception` allows you to pass a 'cause' `Exception` in the constructor so that when you throw an exception in a catch-block, you can append the original exception like this.

Usually when the exception is logged or printed, the output contains the original exception appended with words like "caused by:". Also when you catch such a wrapped exception, you can call `Throwable.getCause()` to retrieve the exception that caused the current exception.

Of course when you forget to add the cause in the constructor, the original exception and the real cause is lost.

Wrapping exceptions is a common practice in cases where the original cause will not tell the user what went wrong, because the message and exception type might be to low-level.